# How to refresh activity while not using the app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, background

I'm working with realtime database where I want my activities to run even no one is using the app.

```
swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener {

    // code

    binding.swipeRefresh.isRefreshing = false
}
```

From the above code, the user needs to swipe to refresh, I want it to be the same but in background and it does itself.

That means the activity is like a 'refresh' in the background every five seconds.

Comment: u can try research on thread. You can manipulate the thread and control them to work.

Comment: The main thread is not going to update your UI when it is off screen. What would be the point of updating something that cannot be seen? Just update it in `onResume()` and it will be up-to-date when the user sees it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to keep an app running while it's not being used.  Android app processes will be killed by Android when the user is no longer using the app, and this can't be prevented.  Android does this to save resources and allow other apps to run when they are being used. I suggest reading the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle) to understand how it works.

Your app should isntead simply query the database again when it's launched and rebuild the UI.